# How can I disable red flags warnings on sublime 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, sublimelinter

I would like to know how can i disable this red flags warnings (**image-link below**) to showing and what is this for and which package belongs? I have to be constantly hitting the X and is disturbing the work flow.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is a built in feature in Sublime; it's controlled by the following setting, which defaults to being turned on:

```json
// Shows build errors just under the line on which they occur.
"show_errors_inline": true,
```

If you turn this off in your user preferences (right hand pane in the `Preferences > Settings` window) it will stop doing that.

If this setting is turned off but you still see these appearing when you build, then you're using a third party package that's not properly respecting the setting; in that case you would need to contact the maintainer of said package and get them to fix that for you.

Comment: Perfect, I just turned it off and it stopped. Thanks for your help!